# Sound when hitting a metal pipe: dependence on radius?

Tags: acoustics, harmonic-oscillator

There's a fun physics exhibit at the Centrum Nauki Kopernik in Warsaw with various hollow metal pipes of different lengths and radii that you can whack with a small mallet. One section has three pipes of identical lengths (maybe a foot/a foot and a half) but different radii, ranging from an inch or so to a cm. As far as I could tell their walls were all the same thickness. I naively assumed that the pipes would produce a lower pitch as they got bigger, but I was wrong: the biggest pipe produced the highest-pitched sound, while the skinny one produced the lowest-pitched sound.

Can anyone help me understand the physics here?

Comment: In general, there will be a lot of different tones (of various frequencies) coming out of a real pipe. We usually teach students that the main tone will depend on the length (the longest dimension) of the pipe and the lowest wavelength will be half the pipe length (if the pipe is open on both ends). But there are a ton of (often unspoken) approximations that go into this simplistic type of calculation. Given that simplistic calculation, all your pipes should sound the same. The *widths* of the pipes probably have some effect on the amplitude of the main tone, which can effect what you hear.

Comment: Since the width of the widest pipe is closest to the length of the pipe, maybe this reinforces the main tone (the tone due to the length). But, I will defer to others to provide an answer.